# How to interpret cell values from statsmodels contingency table methods?

Tags: contingency-tables, statsmodels

The documentation for the methods in statsmodels.stats.contingency_tables.Table is sparse; for example, for `fittedvalues()` it describes it "returns fitted cell counts under independence". What does it fit each value to? The additional information says the returned cell counts are estimates under a model, but what model?

Answer (score 4):

The fitted values are the estimated mean cell counts under the independence model.

If p1 + p2 + ... = 1 are the row probabilities, and
q1 + q2 + ... = 1 are the column probabilities, and N is the total sample size in the table, then N * pi * qj is the fitted value for cell i,j of the table under independence.